# Good results with Linear Regression

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, lstm

I am experimenting with a data set that I have of revenue of few products. It is on a monthly level and I have 6 years of data with me.

As a preprocessing step, I've converted that data set into a lag based data set i.e. the prior month and prior year revenue will be treated as an input to the current month revenue and etc.

With this lagged data set for one product, I've created a linear regression model and also a simple LSTM model. The MAPE for linear regression model was 5% and the MAPE for the LSTM model was approx 15%. I am yet to test for the other products.

As the MAPE for the linear regression model is much less than the LSTM, is it worth investing my time into tuning the LSTM model to get better accuracies ? There is a chance that linear regression did well only for this one product and the other products might have non-linear relationship and LSTM or any other models might work well. What is the general approach for situations like these ? Please let me know if the question is too broad. I've tried fiting the time series models like ARIMA but I really would want to use the additional features instead of relying on just a single variable dataset

Comment: "is it worth investing my time into tuning the LSTM model to get better accuracies ? " Do you need to have a model with MAPE below 5%? If so, continued refinement of your models (LSTM, regression, or otherwise) seems to be necessary. If not, congrats, the problem is solved; proceed to the nearest pub.

Comment: I am good with MAPE below 5% but it's just suspicious that I got good results with a simple lm() call without me having to do much about it excluding the data preparation part.

Comment: You are essentially specifying the form of the Transfer Function (Dynamic Regression Model). It may be possible to improve your model by model diagnostics. See https://autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf for a discussion .